# Xcode 4.2 does not work with folder reference?

Tags: iphone, xcode, reference, ios5, directory

I have problem after installing new XCode 4.2. Everything worked fine with my previous version XCode 4.0.1.

I make a completely new project. If I add a folder reference, when I deploy to the simulator (iOS5) it stucks at "Attaching to ".

If I deploy it to my ipod touch (iOS 5.0.1), it keeps saying: "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier."

Anyone got the same problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom